# How do I set the fonts of item and subitem inside of itemize?

Tags: itemize

I want to set the font of the text and bullet-style of items and subitems inside of itemize. Not sure about the correct syntax.

```
\renewenvironment{itemize}{
  \begin{list}{}{
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.0em}
    \setlength\itemsep{0.5em}
    \sffamily
    \mdseries
    \item 
   \subitem
}
}{
  \end{list}
}
```

Comment: You could take a look at `enumitem` https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem package to create personal list.

Comment: You want to change the font used for the bullet????

Comment: For the text that goes with the bullet.

Comment: What do you mean by `\subitem`? It is a defined command, but should be used only in an index and not by the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple solution with `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=1em, itemsep=0.5em, before=\sffamily\selectfont}

\begin{document}

Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.
\begin{itemize}
\item A description of an item.
\item A description of some other item.
\end{itemize}
Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text.. Some more text. Some more text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The goal is to avoid repetition. I decided to use use setlist so the formatting would apply to all lists.

Comment: This is also possible with `enumitem`. Please see the modified code.